# video play countinously firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i has store the video link using Fire base database and there totally 3 link. and to play the video continuously, without touch the code, if u can show how to play song continuously. sorry for the code, there too may error.

[image: db-format]

```
private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
private DatabaseReference song1;
private DatabaseReference song2;
private DatabaseReference song3;
private VideoView videoView;



protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
  song1 = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Song").child("1");
  song2 = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Song").child("2");
  song3 = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Song").child("3");
  videoView = findViewById(R.id.videoView);
  total = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Song");
------------------------------------------------------------------------

  total.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            List<Uri> list = new ArrayList<>();
            for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                list.add(child.getValue(Uri.class));
                Uri uri=Uri.parse(dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
               videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
               videoView.requestFocus();
               videoView.start();
            }



}
```

Comment: do you want to play song1 followed by song2 followed by song3?

Comment: yes, my plan using looping, but if there better way, its good to try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mplayer) {
        mplayer.setLooping(true);
    }
});
```

You could make a method and pass different url's to it.

```
playVideo(String uri) {

    videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
    videoView.requestFocus();
    videoView.start();
}
```

and while calling the playVideo method check the following condition -

```
if (videoView.isPlaying()) {

}
else {
     playVideo(uri);
}
```

Comment: its work for 3 different song? if u can give me more explanation how to store 3 different data referent in 1 data reference = song1,song2,song3,